# Declaring a shared Pointer within a function produce a leaky memory behavior

Tags: pointers, memory-leaks, c++17, smart-pointers

I‘ve been trying to understand smart pointers, and as I understood, smart pointer will destroy themselves once they are not reachable through the code.

For this reason I was trying to implement a demonstration for this behavior:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<memory>

using namespace std;

void shared(){
    cout<<"Shared Pointer:"<<endl;
shared_ptr<int> number = make_shared<int>(50);

cout<<*number<<endl;
cout<<number<<endl;
}

int main(){

int address;
shared();

cout<<"please enter the targeted address:"<<endl;
cin>>address;
int *pointer = (int *) address;

cout<<"we found this number: "<<*pointer<<endl;
}
```

output:

```
Shared Pointer:
50
0xf28c30
please enter the targeted address:
15895600 // I just converted the hexdecimal above to decimal number.
we found this number: 50
```

So I‘m able to retrieve the value 50 from outside the function `shared()`, by manually entering its address in the console.
Isn‘t supposed to be null or random number? If this is normal then how smartpointers are made to avoid memory leaks!?

P.S: doing the same test using a normal pointer will produce the same results unless we add `delete pointer;` (which is the expected behavior)

I appreciate any idea about this specific behavior.

Comment: I believe your are facing a crash or an unwanted behavior because you cannot cast an integer to a pointer integer. Should be int * pointer= &address

Comment: you can cast an integer to a pointer integer. try it...

Answer (score 0):

To make sure that the memory was deleted it is better to test the smart pointers with a class

```
class Greeting {
public:
    Greeting()
    {
        std::cout << "Hello" << std::endl;
    }

    ~Greeting()
    {
        std::cout << "Bye" << std::endl;
    }
};

void shared() {
    shared_ptr<Greeting> var = make_shared<Greeting>();
}

int main() {
    std::cout << "Start" << std::endl;
    shared();
    std::cout << "End" << std::endl;
}
```

You will get the following output:

```
Start //Start of the main
Hello // When creating the object (the resource)
Bye   // **When destructing the object (the resource)**
End //End the main
```

Comment: this looks good, but still not answering my question.